# Rotation of triangle in opengl

Tags: opengl

I m new in opengl.I ant to rotate my triangle when keypressed.My triangle is not display.It may be there must have lots of bug in code plz review it and give proper suggestion.Below is the code of rotation..

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{


   switch (key) {

      case 'q':
         exit(0);
         break;

         case 'a':
             {

            glPushMatrix();
            glLoadIdentity();
            glTranslatef(0,0,0);
            glRotatef(90.0+rot, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);        
                glVertex3f( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 );        
                glVertex3f( 3.0, 2.0, 0.0 );        
                glVertex3f( 3.0, 1.0, 0.0 );        
              glEnd();
            glPopMatrix();

                rot+=1;

             }
         break;
   }
}
```

and from MAIN FUNCTION this function is calling by below line of code.

......

```
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
```

.......

Comment: Since you are not seeing anything, the very first problem is with view point. What is the view point location ?

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using glut (not a great idea, IMO, but such is life) you normally want to put all your drawing code in one place, and pass (a pointer to) that function (or one that calls it) to `glutDisplayFunc`. In your keyboard function, you'd just do something like:

```
rot+=1;
glutPostRedisplay();
```

The `glutPostRedisplay()` means a message is (at least conceptually) posted to a queue to say that the display needs to be updated. Based on that, whatever function you've passed to `glutDisplayFunc` will get invoked (though not necessarily immediately).

If you've done any Windows API programming, this is virtually identical to the usual pattern there: when you receive input, you modify the data, and invalidate your windows' rectangle. In response to that, you'll receive a WM_PAINT message, and your code will then update the display. Though the details differ, you see similar patterns with MacOS and the X windowing system as well.

Answer (score 2):

First off, your controller code should only handle incrementing the rotation

```
case 'a':
   rot += 1;
   break;
```

Your main display function should handle everything else. What might be happening is that your implementation is rotating and showing the triangle but then main loop then immediately changes your view.

Comment: I have a function display which is in loop from main.I should chek my keypressed from that function ?

Comment: i have paste this code in display function but still triagle is not appearing. why ?

Comment: i written this in main display function and only controlling rot variable but my triangle is not appearing..